# How I get a list of substrings ignoring the new line symbol

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a text like this:

```
Title
<bp n=3 /> bla bla bla
bla bla bla <bp n=4 /> bla bla bla
<bp n=5 /> bla bla bla
<bp n=6 /> bla bla bla <bp n=7 /> bla bla bla
bla bla bla
```

And I need to get a list like this:

```
['<bp n=3 /> bla bla bla
bla bla bla','<bp n=4 /> bla bla bla','<bp n=5 /> bla bla bla','<bp n=6 /> bla bla bla ','<bp n=7 /> bla bla bla
bla bla bla']
```

I've tried to use a code like this:

```
re.findall(r'(<bp n=\d+ />.*?)<bp n=\d+ />',text,re.DOTALL)
```

then it jumped over the next match

Comment: Try `r'<bp n=\d+ />[^<]*'` or `r'<bp n=\d+ />.*?(?=<bp n=\d+ />|\Z)'`

Comment: Thank you the     r'<bp n=\d+ />.*?(?=<bp n=\d+ />|\Z)' worked

Comment: Your text looks like an XML. Consider to use `lxml` lib instead of regex to parse XML source code

Answer (score 0):

The `<bp n=\d+ />` at the end of your pattern matches a part of the subsequent match. You may use

```
re.findall(r'<bp n=\d+ />.*?(?=<bp n=\d+ />|\Z)', text, re.DOTALL)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9IvSow/1).

Here, `(?=<bp n=\d+ />|\Z)` matches a *location* in string that is immediately followed with `<bp n=`, 1+ digits,  `/>`, or end of string (`\Z`).